# How to copy multi module artifacts from repository to another?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to find out what would be the best way to copy an existing artifact from one repository to another one.

It is possible to do it manually with the maven-deploy-plugin, but what is when I have a multi module porject?

Manually, I would download all modules (f.e. with maven-dependency-plugin and its goal copy-dependencies) and deploy them manually with maven-deploy-plugin using right arguments.

How can I do it on the maven way?

Comment: You can try [maven-stage-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-stage-plugin/) currently a new release is undergoing...available in a few days...MIght be worth a try...

Comment: I will wait for the release, the snapshots doesn't work for me today.